Deposits for Solana Not Showing in Solana Activity in Phantom Wallet
Made three withdrawals from central exchange to Phantom Wallet. Only first one shows in wallet activity. All three show success on Solana Explorer. Don't recall what Solana balance was prior to these deposits, but it's possible they have been credited. Not 100% sure. I just wanted to be able to confirm by seeing the line item deposits. Two out of three are not listed. I've never had this happen before...disconcerting. Phantom Wallet appears to have no customer service. Apparently this wallet isn't reliable. Will this mess up records for taxes? How to correct? What's a better wallet than Phantom?
